# Grid CSS - Two separate parents with same height children

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I have two separate divs (parents) with their own set of children. The number of children can vary depending over time. Some might be removed while others are added. The heights of the children can vary depending how much content there is.

The issue I'm dealing with is trying to make all children for both parents the same height. In a previous attempt, I tried only having one parent that contained all the children with "Section 2" inserted before the second set of children, but when adding new children, it breaks. For example, children meant for Section 2 appeared above the Section 2 title. Here's where I am now... going back to two separate divs.

```css
:root {
  --primary-blue: #2a88a6;
  --black: #333333;
  --body-copy: #4f4f4f;
  --body-copy-inverse: #ffffff;
  --chart-dark-gray: #828282;
  --chart-light-gray: #e0e0e0;
  --yellow: #fed895;
}
.callout {
  background-color: var(--chart-dark-gray);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
.callout > h5 {
  color: var(--yellow);
}
.doc-details-grid-wrapper {
  margin: 40px 0 50px;
}

.doc-details-grid-wrapper h4 {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.doc-details-title {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.doc-details-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  margin: 10px 0 50px;
  min-height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

.doc-details-grid > a {
  background-color: #2a88a6;
}

.doc-details-grid > a:hover {
  background-color: #136a85;
}

.doc-details-grid > a:last-child {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.doc-details-grid h5 {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.doc-details-grid p {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.doc-details-grid > div > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box {
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: var(--bs-border-radius-lg) !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead {
    max-width: none;
    min-height: 70vh;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: calc(1rem + 2.3vw);
    margin: unset !important;
  }
  .docs-grid > a {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .doc-details-grid > a {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: calc(33% - 40px);
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1 justify-content-center">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <div class="doc-details-grid-wrapper">
        <div class="doc-details-title">
          <h4>Section 1</h4>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="doc-details-grid">
          <a href="" class="box callout">
            <h5>Section 1 Box 1</h5>
            <p>Short description goes here. This is where you can provide a brief preview about the contents of the downloadable PDF document.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="" class="box callout">
            <h5>Section 1 Box 2</h5>
            <p>Short description goes here.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="" class="box callout">
            <h5>Section 1 Box 3</h5>
            <p>This is where you can provide a brief preview about the contents of the downloadable PDF document.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="" class="box callout">
            <h5>Section 1 Box 4</h5>
            <p>This is where you can provide a brief preview about the contents of the downloadable PDF document. This description is a little longer than the others.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="" class="box callout">
            <h5>Section 1 Box 5</h5>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <div class="doc-details-grid-wrapper">
        <div class="doc-details-title">
          <h4>Section 2</h4>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="doc-details-grid">
          <a href="" class="box callout">
            <h5>Section 2 Box 1</h5>
            <p>Short description goes here.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="" class="box callout">
            <h5>Section 2 Box 2</h5>
            <p>Short description goes here.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="" class="box callout">
            <h5>Section 2 Box 3</h5>
            <p>This is where you can provide a brief preview.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="" class="box callout">
            <h5>Section 2 Box 4</h5>
            <p>This description is a little longer than the others.</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you want all of the boxes to be the same height you could add a height rule to `.callout` or `.box`, like `height:200px;`

Comment: why not rewrite this to just use flex.  if the two parent divs are different heights use js to set the smaller one to equal the larger one